# разница / разность / различие / отличие

Tags: значения, разница

I'm awfully confused about the difference between the four nouns with the meaning 'difference'. Some example sentences showing which to use in which situation would greatly help my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

*Разница* - ***difference***:

> - В чём **разница** между этим словарём и тем? (What's the difference between this dictionary and that one?)
> - Я не вижу никакой **разницы** между этими двумя книгами. (I don't see any difference between these two books.)

*Разность* - ***difference*** (the **result of the subtraction** of one number, quantity, etc, from another):

> - Найдите **разность** между 700 и 400. Ответ - 300. (Find the difference between 700 and 400. The answer is 300.)

So, personally, I associate *разность* with the mathematical operation. I never use *разность* the way I use *разница*. When it comes to the state or quality of being unlike, use *разница*.

*Различие*, *отличие* - ***distinction***:

> - Есть очевидные **различия (отличия)** между двумя винодельными    регионами. (There are obvious distinctions between the two wine-making areas).
> - Он **проводит различие** (NOT отличие in this set expression) между    искусством и культурой. (He draws a distinction between art and
>     culture.)
> - Я пока на **провёл различия** между удовольствием читать и писать. (I did not yet make a distinction between the pleasures of reading and of
>     writing fiction.)

So, remember the expression **проводить различия**. Alternatively, you might say **находить отличия**. Again, it's a set expression:

> - **Найдите пять отличий** на картинках. (Spot the 5 differences in the pictures.)

Note that we *wouldn't* say найдите пять разниц. But I see that it's possible to say найдти пять различий, though I'd prefer найдите пять отличий. Perhaps, it's just a matter of preference here.

Also, remember the expression **в отличие от** (meaning *unlike*):

> - **В отличие от тебя**, я знаю, чего хочу. (Unlike you, I know what I want.)

Please note that some people have commented that "проводить различие/различия между" is not a natural Russian collocation. I beg to differ, and here is some evidence to support my argument: [source 1](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=7n-ZBU5z36oC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20english&source=bl&ots=78w6hZP74n&sig=aV_uGjcgbcaW89WE_4BZ9m1b-Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlz_CSoZzeAhXPdHAKHaeMAJIQ6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20english&f=false) and [source 2](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=uUy5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP49&lpg=PP49&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83&source=bl&ots=C3bg-ybTky&sig=g8vjmcM32BjclFrEM1LNM4pTT74&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu4vb3mJzeAhUJPXAKHYHkDaMQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83&f=false).

Comment: "Проводить различия (-е)" sounds really weird, though it can be found in some sources. "Находить различие", "искать отличия", "видеть разницу" are far better. But видеть отличия, for example, is also ok.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "Проводить различие" used. I'm a native speaker.

Comment: @Misamoto You must have heard this phrase. Perhaps, you just don't remember. I'm a native speaker too.

Comment: @Misamoto check this out http://context.reverso.net/перевод/русский-английский/провести+различие+между

Comment: @Misamoto https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=uUy5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP49&lpg=PP49&dq=давайте+проведем+различие+между&source=bl&ots=C3bg-ybTky&sig=g8vjmcM32BjclFrEM1LNM4pTT74&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu4vb3mJzeAhUJPXAKHYHkDaMQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=давайте%20проведем%20различие%20между&f=false

Comment: @ElenaYefimova please check this out https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=uUy5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP49&lpg=PP49&dq=давайте+проведем+различие+между&source=bl&ots=C3bg-ybTky&sig=g8vjmcM32BjclFrEM1LNM4pTT74&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu4vb3mJzeAhUJPXAKHYHkDaMQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=давайте%20проведем%20различие%20между&f=false

Comment: @ElenaYefimova and this may also be interesting http://context.reverso.net/перевод/русский-английский/провести+различие+между

Comment: @Enguroo I mentioned the fact that you can come across it in some books. But still I can hardly remember hearing or saying that.

Comment: @ElenaYefimova perhaps, it's just not the most common collocation with "различие" but it's natural and not weird at all.

Comment: @Enguroo here are three educated native speakers saying it is weird. But I do not insist, that's your own choice, sure. )))))

Comment: @ElenaYefimova thank you anyway :-) But who is the second and third? There are three people commenting. Misamoto said he hadn't heard it before, I said the phrase was fine, you said it was weird. It may be after all... Anything can be considered weird in certain csituations. Recently I heard a native Russian speaker calling himself артер (instead of художник). To me it was weird, but it wasn't to him and some other artists around. But it's another story...

Comment: @Enguroo ok, let it be two of us, nevertheless. You know, that happens sometimes to artists... )))))

Comment: Is there a difference in use between "есть то́нкая *ра́зница* ме́жду двумя́ слова́ми" and "есть то́нкое *разли́чие* ме́жду двумя́ слова́ми"?

Comment: @MrVocabulary there is no difference. I think which phrase to use is just a matter of preference. Both are natural collocations.

Comment: I did a bit of digging in dictionaries and it seems to me that: разница is any divergence in properties, различие is something made or perceived, and отличие is an external manifestation of difference. In many cases these seem to functionally be the same. Like, суще́ственные/незначи́тельные отли́чия point to what you see as разница. That was an instructive post of yours :)

Comment: PS. Didn't you miss one comma? → в отли́чие от тебя́, я зна́ю_,_ чего́ хочу́

Comment: @MrVocabulary Yes, I missed a comma. Thanks.